# How to group rows with same value in dataframe using repartition

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark and the Java api for Spark so my code is not in scala or python.

I have a `Dataset<Row>` dataframe that I want to partition based on a column ID value that the rows share:

```
df.repartition("the_id_value")
```

The result is that all rows with the same ID are together in the same partition, but each partition consists of many different groups of those rows. For example, all rows with ID=1 and ID=2 are put into the same partition.

I need to iterate through each partition and process the data and would like it if the partition only contained rows from 1 unique ID instead of multiple IDs. I understand that this means there will a much larger number of partitions. I either need repartition to work in a way where only rows of one specific ID is present in each partition, or after repartitioning, I can further group the rows in each partition based on that unique ID again. Any ideas on how to do that? The goal is that I can iterate, create an Object (I need to make 1 Object for every unique ID) using the Rows.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote you basically want to group all the rows having the same id.

So why not just use groupBy ?

```
myDataset.groupBy("the_id_value")
```

then you can apply whatever logic you want, like create an object from the aggregation of all rows. Of course, you can mix both repartition and groupBy for better performance.

See some examples:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-groupby-on-dataframe/?expand_article=1

Comment: I do not need to aggregate anything in my data. I thought groupBy was for if I needed to aggregate any fields?

Comment: Yes, you basically want to group data by an id and then apply your logic on all the rows in this group right ? groupBy aggreggation is basically that, no ?

Comment: To add to the previous comment:

The groupBy will assure you that you have all the rows sharing the same id together, then you can apply a user defined aggregator function if it's complex processing, otherwise try to keep in-house functions for optimization purpose.

`myDataset.groupBy("the_id_value").agg(myCustomUDF("*"))`
 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html